# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken returns invalid authentication code

Tags: android, access-token

I use the following to get an authentication that I can access a backend from an Android app. This is described here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("oauth2:server:client_id:");
sb.append(getString(R.string.google_app_id));
sb.append(":api_scope:");
sb.append("profile email");
final String scope = sb.toString();
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Activity.this, mAuthAccount, scope);
```

(mAuthAccount was previously set using AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent.)

The above returns a short lived authentication code which sometimes has expired. I would like to check it against google servers, but calling https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token= with the returned token string from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken returns "invalid token".

How do I verify that the authentication code has not expired before I try to use it?

Edit: The returned string is not a token, but an authorization code which can be exchanged with a google API to obtain a token (The returned string begins with "/4" and not "/1" or "/2" if I remember correctly).

The code does not always work (on my server) and I would love to be able to check if the code can be used or has expired.

Comment: I get {"error":"invalid_token"} from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo after a call to GoogleAuthUtil.getToken - the token was *just* generated and not tempered with. Maybe the type of the token is wrong?

Comment: Also, I tried to invalidate the token and calling GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() again. I still got an invalid token reply from googleapis.com. This is what I don't understand. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: did you solved your issue? what was your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `app_id` to get oauth token, You just need to change scope

```
"oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN
```

In this case your scope can be plus.login

More Info:

[Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth)

[Scopes Class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes)

Comment: I'm not getting a token. I'm getting a short lived authentication code. How is it possible to obtain the same code can be twice?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [Validating the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken) documentation:

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo
>
> Accepts an access token and returns information about that access
>   token including which application was it issued to, the intended
>   target of the token, the scopes the user consented to, the remaining
>   lifetime of the token, and the user ID.
>
> Below is an example of such a request:
>
> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg
> ```
>
> The TokenInfo endpoint will respond with a JSON array that describes the token or an error.
>
> On the wire, the response looks similar to the following:
>
> ```
> {
>   "audience":"8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com",
>   "user_id":"123456789",
>   "scope":"profile email",
>   "expires_in":436
> }
> ```
>
> If the token has expired, has been tampered with, or the permissions
>   revoked, the Google Authorization Server will respond with an error.
>   The error surfaces as a 400 status code, and a JSON body as follows:
>
> ```
> {"error":"invalid_token"}
> ```
>
> By design, no additional information is given as to the reason for the failure.

So `invalid_token` is a valid answer when the token has expired, has been tampered with, or the permissions revoked

**EDIT**

It is possible to receive `invalid_token` just after the token is returned from `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken` because GoogleAuthUtil may have cached it. In this case you should call `GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken`.

You can find more information here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html

**EDIT 2**

I just notice that you are missing https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login in your scope. Please try to add it because seems mandatory to use Cross-client Identity.

Comment: I'm using "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" as part of the scope. The returned token (string) is always invalid according to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=<token>. I also found https://github.com/googledrive/crossclientoauth2-android which should be a working example.

Comment: I see only `profile email` as `api_scope` in the code you posted. Can you update your code with the last edits you made?

Answer (score 0):

The token retrieved by `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` in this fashion is not an access token, it's an ID token.

Try the following URL instead (note `id_token` query parameter instead of `access_token`):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=<ID TOKEN>
```